# Position of first word of string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, cpu-word, position

I originally used indexOf to find a space but I want to find any word boundary.

Something like this, but what regex?

```
var str = "This is a sentence",
firstword = str.search("");
return word;
```

I want to return "This". Even in the case of a tab, period, comma, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var str = "This is a sentence"; 
return str.split(/\b/)[0];
```

Although you would probably want to check that there was a match like this:

```
var str = "This is a sentence"; 
var matches = str.split(/\b/);
return matches.length > 0 ? matches[0] : "";
```

Comment: Only just. I rarely use JS so was happy we got the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

This splits the string at every word boundary and returns the first one:

```
var str = "This is a sentence";
firstword = str.split(/\b/)[0];
```